# Display 2 rows: shipping tax and products tax in order totals section for orders, invoices, credit memos

Tags: shipping, tax

Instead of :

```
Tax: £30
```

I would like to display in the backend for orders/credit memos/invoices:

```
Shipping tax: £2
Product Tax: £28
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an extension that will add a block containing Shipping&Product Tax to the layout for orders/credit memos/invoices.

For example, to add somewhat like this: "Shipping tax: £2", one needs to `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/your_module.xml`:

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="order_totals">
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="tax_item" template="your_module/tax_item.phtml" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

To get the same for credit memos/invoices, you need to add the following:

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_view>
    <reference name="invoice_totals">
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="tax_item" template="your_module/tax_item.phtml" />
    </reference>        
</adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_view>

<adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_view>
    <reference name="creditmemo_totals">
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="tax_item" template="your_module/tax_item.phtml" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_view>
```

In `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/your_module/tax_item.phtml`:

```
<?php $source = $this->getSource(); ?>
<tr>
    <td class="label">
        <div class="summary-collapse"> Shipping tax </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="price"><?php echo $source->getShippingTaxAmount() ?></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```